# Is an elevon (elevator + aileron) considered as an all-moving control surface?

Tags: flight-controls, ailerons, elevator

The delta wing on Concorde uses [elevon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevon) as its control surface. Is the elevon considered as all-moving control surface?

Answer (score 7):

An All-Moving control surface is a surface where the complete structure acts as a stabilizer. For example, in case of a horizontal tailplane which can be completely moved to work as an Elevator - instead of just the trailing edge of the horizontal tailplane moving to work as a control surface. In such cases, it is called a Stabilator (Stabilizer + Elevator). Elevon is a control surface which is part of the main wing, but the trailing edge of the wing is moved to get Yaw and Roll control. This makes Elevon a normal control surface and **Not** an all moving surface.